# Can i split HTML elements into separate rows? Power automate

Tags: html, power-automate

For a project I'm currently working on I have to get a certain part of an email message and put it into a SharePoint list, its almost fully functional but there is still one small part that doesn't work,

The part of the email contains websites, so I choose to trim the rest of the email so that the websites remain,

This is the current output:
Example.coexample.com

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
<br />
Example.co<br />
Example.com
```

Is there a easy fix for this? there is nothing I can split on except on the HTML Elements but I don't know if that's possible, when I searched for it I couldn't find anything, but these are the elements between the 2 sites:

[image: HTML Elements]

`<br> <li><b>Example.co</b></li><li><b>Example.com</b></li> <br> <br>`

(I had to post it as a picture because if I put it here as text it would display as a bulletpoint)

is there a way I can spilt here? or is there another way that i should do this?

[image: The flow I'm currently using]

This is what im supposed to do right? when i tested this it gives the same output as before, and when i check what the update domain array contains its this: [] so it seems empty

Comment: Can you post the full example as code? It won’t format it as a bullet if you do that.

Comment: <br>
<li><b>Example.co</b></li><li><b>Example.com</b></li>
<br>
<br>

Comment: I meant paste it back into your question. I can do that though.

Comment: Are the domains always contained within the bold tag?

Comment: Yes i think so, in this example containing 2 websites, in other examples the same bold tag is used

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

[image: Flow]

The first step is the above HTML you provided.

The second step does some work to make the HTML a valid markup for XML.  Basically, I just remove the `<br>` tags because they don't close, they only open.  Other tags like `<b>` and `<i>` always close in your example so they're fine and actually help with the outcome.

I also put the `<xml>` tag at the start and end so it has a root node.

This is the expression within the second step ...

```
concat(concat('<xml>', replace(variables('HTML'), '<br>', '')), '</xml>')
```

Then in the final step, I use xpath to extract the result.  This is the expression ...

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//b/text()')
```

... and this is the end result ...

[image: Result]

If the rules I have applied hold up then you should be good to go.  If there are more complications that you've failed to mention then let me know and I can see what I can do.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work, i added a picture to the post of my current flow

Comment: Ultimately, I need the EXACT text you’re working with. What comes out of the “Trim all except websites” call and show me the expression into the “Initialize XML” step.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant share the exact sites due to private info, but the outputs of Trim all except websites are as follows: example.coexample.com. the initialize XML is empty when i create it, then inside of the loop I update it to the XPath code you provided

Comment: You can mask the exact sites but with the original text you provided, is that literally all of it? Given I managed the correct output, something is either 1) different to what you gave me or 2) there’s something not quite right with your implementation of my answer.

Comment: Yes that was what i was thinking too, i think i might have implemented it wrong, is this the right expression i should use in the Update XML? ```concat(concat('<xml>', replace(variables('Trim_all_except_websites'), '<br>', '')), '</xml>')``` ?

Comment: The trim step isn’t a variable is it? It’s a data operations step of some sort, so what is that? Is it a compose? If so, you’ll need to modify that part of the statement. I thought that would throw an error though if it was wrong. If you looks at the runtime outputs, does the Initialize XML step actually give you a proper XML output with all of the text as expected?